# How to show the name of the underlying library and form in InfoMaker/Powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

I am running InfoMaker for reports, and would like to show the name of the underlying form and the underlying library in the report itself.  Does anyone know how to get this?  The closest thing I see is the Describe function, but that seems to work one level deeper than I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display the library name in InfoMaker at design time, I have no idea.

*But* if you need to display the library name at run time, I would add a computed field in the report and set its expression from the code that opens the report.

Something like `dw.modify("c_lib.expression='" + classname() + "'")` where `c_lib` is the name of that computed field. Warning, do not call `classname()` from inside a global function, as it make PB crash...

Comment: Thank you.  This is at run time, not design time.  But I do not have access to the code that runs the report, so cannot set that computed field, unfortunately.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As a cheat you can just hard-code the library and dynamically get the dataobject on the fly (your reports shouldn't change libraries once written too often, most never do.), or pick it up from a datastore that lists them out from a table in the database that keeps them organised in one place. take the dataobject and search the datastore for the associated library. you'll need to upkeep the table, but this should get you down the line...

Comment: The $10 point is that he just has access to the inners of the DW, in InfoMaker and cannot modify any PB code. Do you know a trick to get the dataobject from inside a DW ? If so, I am greatly interested ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the code that runs the reports you will have to add the information to the report itself. I would write a small program that loads each DataWindow from a library into a DataWindow control, adds or updates a text control that has the information you want, and saves the DataWindow back to the library. When the program updates the text it should only the text property of the control, not the position, band, etc. That way you can set it up to add the text in the right place for most of your reports, and any you adjust by hand will stay where you put them. Be sure to make the text big enough to hold the longest form + library combination. You can get the syntax you need to create the text by adding the text to one of the reports and looking at the exported syntax. Use a name for the text object that will not collide with anything existing in your reports - something long and ugly.